# Asp.net,Menu control

Tags: asp.net, menu, internet-explorer-8

Asp Menu control is not rendered as the way it has in IE 8 and IE 9.please help to fix this issue.It is padded with white space or the sub menus are not displayed properly sometimes.

Comment: we need some more info. we cant help you like this

Answer (score 0):

compability mode error,

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
</head>
```